# PyAutoGUI, Stop Command

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm actually doing a script using Pyautogui, that control my mouse and uses my browser. My problem is that I want the script to stop the following actions or the following mouse movements and clicks if the last click wasn't a click on an hypertext link or something like that!

This is my code:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(118, 417, duration = 1) #immeuble A11 adductabilité
pyautogui.click(117, 418,)
pyautogui.moveTo(118, 418, duration = 1)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
pyautogui.moveTo(419, 1064, duration = 0.1) #go down to Internet explorer
pyautogui.click(419, 1064,)
pyautogui.moveTo(543, 955, duration = 0.1)
# click on Internet explorer
pyautogui.click(543, 955,)
pyautogui.moveTo(1630, 112, duration = 0.1) # click on Rechercher (IPON)
pyautogui.click(1630, 112,)
pyautogui.moveTo(1661, 470, duration = 0.1) # click on Rechercher IMMEUBLE
pyautogui.click(1661, 470,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maby check where it is on the screen and cancel the code if it hovers over the wrong place?

Comment: i don't want to check it manually, i want the program to search for the Immeuble automaticaly if nothing appear in the search so i want the program to abort the next steps and go to search for the next IMB that's what i want to do :( is it possible or no !!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little bit tricky: you need to track changes of your browser's URL. If it was changed, that means you've clicked the hyperlink.

```
import pyautogui
from tkinter import Tk


def get_url():
    """ Return current browser URL """
    pyautogui.click(150, 50, duration=1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    return Tk().clipboard_get()


url = get_url()
pyautogui.click(500, 500)  # do something
if url != get_url():
    print("URL was changed!")
    # execute here 10 lines of code
# rest of the code here
```

But it's far more effective to use [selenium](https://selenium.dev/) when you have to deal with web browser.

Comment: yeah it helps me, but is it possible to not stop the script but just to skip for example the next 10 lignes in the script !!i mean automatically when url wasn't changed the program need to skip the next 10 lignes and continue the script !! is it possible

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you should better use Selenium for this type of manipulation : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/.

Comment: yeah i think it's useful thank you bro, sorry i'm beginner to python :(  is it possible so to use Pyautogui and selenium in same script !!

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a suggestion